# How to pass directives (kind of proxy) to inside the component?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a button with material:

```
<button mat-button (click)="clicked = true">
  Basic button
</button>
```

And I wrap this button with my component:

```
<csv-button>

@Component({
  selector: 'csv-button',
  template: `
    <button (click)="clicked = true">
      Basic button
    </button>
  `
})
export class CSVButtonComponent  { }
```

I want to add `mat-button` or `mat-menu-item` to my `csv-button` component.

The problem is those directives are applied only to `button`. so I looking for a way to pass this directives into the component.

So when I add `mat-button` to `<csv-button>`: `<csv-button mat-button>` is the same as `<button mat-button ..` inside `<csv-button>` component.

And when I add `mat-menu-item` to `<csv-button>`: `<csv-button mat-menu-item>` is the same as `<button mat-menu-item ..` inside `<csv-button>` component.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can not do it. But you can get if you has an attribute "mat-input" and use *ngIf. For know if you has an attributte use Optional Attribute, some like

```
constructor(@Optional() @Attribute('mat-button') private isMatButton:any,
            @Optional() @Attribute('mat-menu-item') private isMatMenu:any
            ...
          ){}
```

And your .html

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="isMatButton!==null">
    <button mat-button>click</button>
 </ng-container>
 ...
```

Comment: Well.. I don't know. the problem with this solution is I need to implement the attributes and in each variant for example color, mat-rasied-button and so on.. bassiclly the component will have duplicate code and a lot of *ngif and ng-conatiners..

Comment: I think that it's not possible your approach -even you inject Element Ref and iterate over elementRef.nativeElement.attributes and use Renderer2-. ¿why not use `<ng-conten>`, see e.g. https://netbasal.com/create-advanced-components-in-angular-e0655df5dde6 ?. Well, your .html becomes like <csv-button><button mat-button>..</button></csv-button>,